# OBB-OBB Point of Intersection

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, game-physics

I have looked at a couple of threads about finding the point of intersection between two OBBs.  I still don't understand how to find the axis of least penetration.  I need to find the axis of least penetration which I believe is also termed the last separating axis in David Eberly's paper to figure out which portion of the table I should use to calculate the intersection point.  This is the paper and the pages of interest start at 9 http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DynamicCollisionDetection.pdf.
So how do I find the axis of least penetration/last separating axis?

Answer (score 2):

The thing at work here is the Separating Axis Theorem
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem.

As is hinted there, for polygon meshes, the possibly separating axes to test are the face normals of the two objects and the cross products.

Since OBBs have 6 faces where 2 are parallel each, you have unique 3 normal per OBB.

Another 3x3 for the cross products, gives 3+3+3x3=16 normals to test.

Project your two OBBs on lines defined by these normals and a point, e.g. the origin.

If the projections overlap, you have no contact (therefore, "separating" axes).

What you are asking for is the axis of least penetration, which seems not be covered directly in Eberly's paper.

You would have to compare the overlap of all projections, and take the least one. This would be your overlap depth. Calculating R - (R_0 + R_1) for each axis from Eberly's table 1 on page 7 should do the trick (just note that the common division L*L which is left out from top of page 6 has to be done to get the real overlapping depth).

A code example at open dynamics engine:
http://sourceforge.net/p/opende/code/1939/tree/trunk/ode/src/box.cpp
(ignore their fudge_factor if you want strictly to get the axes of least overlap).

Bullet physics has something similar, I guess.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification!  I thought I only had to test 15 axis but I know what you meant.  So just to make sure I need to find the result of R-(R_0 + R_1)/(||L||*||L||).  Anotherwords should I divide the R-(R_0 + R_1) by the magnitude of L squared to find the actual distance?

Comment: L being the axis tested

Comment: Yes, that should be true, at least for the first 6 axes. From the back of my head I think it should be the same for the other 9, but feel free to check the formulas on page 6 onward to verify.

Comment: I found out through a test that when the normals of the OBBs are in  parallel the R-(R_0 + R_1) equals 0.  R = R_0 = R_1 = 0.  Thus the normal of the collision is a 0,0,0 vector.  I'm not sure how to handle this.

Comment: You are right, this case can occur due to parallelity (the cross product vanishes). You can ignore this axis then - the other axes are gonna handle it in this case. Visualizing the parallel configuration helps in understanding why.

Comment: One quick question is the function Sign(a) equivalent to (a/|a|).  Or is it the sin trig function.

Comment: The first one - almost, for 0 it is 0.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_(mathematics).